# Turn list of Result into Result of list inside a computation expression?

Tags: f#, computation-expression

I have a `Result<'T, 'E> list` that I would like to turn into a single `Result<'T list, 'E>` following these rules:

- If any `Result` is an `Error` then the result should be an `Error`
- If the result is an `Error` it should be the first `Error` in the list
- If every result is an `OK` then the result should be an `Ok` and the list order should be maintained

So I had a go and implemented this as follows:

```
let all xs = 
  let folder = fun state next -> 
    match (state, next) with 
    | (Result.Ok ys, Result.Ok y) -> ys |> List.append [ y ] |> Result.Ok
    | (Result.Error e, _) -> Result.Error e 
    | (_, Result.Error e) -> Result.Error e 
  Seq.fold folder (Result.Ok []) xs
```

However, this seems like something that might already have been implemented in the standard library. Has it?

Second, I have a computation expression for `Result` like this:

```
type ResultBuilder () = 
  member this.Bind(x, f) = 
    match x with 
    | Result.Ok o -> f o
    | Result.Error e -> Result.Error e
  member this.Return(value) = Result.Ok value
  member this.ReturnFrom(value) = value

let result = new ResultBuilder()
```

I can use `all` inside of a `result { ... }` but is further integration possible? For example by implementing `ResultBuilder.For`?

Comment: It's not in FSharpCore, but some extension libraries have that function implemented, in [F#+](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpPlus) for instance it's called `sequence` and it works for any [Traversable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a `Result<'a, 'e> list` and want a `Result<'a list, 'e>`. That sounds like the `sequence` function described in https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/elevated-world-4/ (which has nothing to do with `seq`s, despite what the name sounds like). A quick check of https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/result.fs suggests that this function hasn't been implemented in the standard FSharp.Core library, so you'll need to implement it yourself.

BTW, if you haven't already read Scott Wlaschin's "Elevated World" series, I don't recommend starting in the middle with the article I linked. Start with [this article](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/elevated-world/) instead, as it builds the background knowledge you need to understand what the "traverse" and "sequence" functions do. Then you'll know the general pattern for implementing one of those functions.

As for your second question, could you provide a few more specifics? For example, what behavior do you want out of `ResultBuilder.For`? The normal behavior expected of a `for` expression would be to take a `Result<'a, 'e> list` (or seq or array) and run the inner block once for every `Result<'a, 'e>` that's in the list or seq or array. If you tried to use your `all` function here, you'd have a type mismatch between `Result<'a, 'e>` (which is what F# would expect a CE's `.For` method to produce) and `Result<'a list, 'e>` which is what your `all` method is returning. What specifically do you want your `ResultBuilder.For` method to do?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. What's the corresponding concept of sequence in Haskell? I read a bit of Haskell enough to understand that bind is monad, map is functor and apply is applicative functor. But couldn't connect sequence to what in haskell yet. TIA!

Comment: [F# for Fun and Profit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/) is the XKCD of the F# world

Answer (score 8):

This functionality is provided by the [`FsToolkit.ErrorHandling`](https://github.com/demystifyfp/FsToolkit.ErrorHandling) package. The function `List.sequenceResultM` will return either:

- A `Result.Ok` containing a list of all `Ok` values
- Or, a `Result.Error` containing just the first `Error` value

There is also a variant `List.sequenceResultA` that returns a list of all errors found.

```ml
#r "nuget: FsToolkit.ErrorHandling, 2.0.0"

open FsToolkit.ErrorHandling

let xs : Result<int, string> list =
  [
    Ok 123
    Ok 456
  ]

let xa = List.sequenceResultA xs // Ok [123; 456]
let xm = List.sequenceResultM xs // Ok [123; 456]

printfn "xa: %A" xa
printfn "xm: %A" xm

let ys =
  [
    Ok 123
    Ok 456
    Error "abc"
    Ok 789
  ]

let ya = List.sequenceResultA ys // Error ["abc"]
let ym = List.sequenceResultM ys // Error "abc"

printfn "ya: %A" ya
printfn "ym: %A" ym

let zs =
  [
    Ok 123
    Error "abc"
    Error "def"
    Ok 456
  ]

let za = List.sequenceResultA zs // Error ["abc"; "def"]
let zm = List.sequenceResultM zs // Error "abc"

printfn "za: %A" za
printfn "zm: %A" zm
```

```
xa: Ok [123; 456]
xm: Ok [123; 456]
ya: Error ["abc"]
ym: Error "abc"
za: Error ["abc"; "def"]
zm: Error "abc"
```

In terms of computation expressions (also provided by `FsToolkit.ErrorHandling`), you could do:

```ml
#r "nuget: FsToolkit.ErrorHandling, 2.0.0"

open FsToolkit.ErrorHandling

let printAll xs =
  result {
    let! xs = List.sequenceResultA xs

    for x in xs do
      printfn "%A" x
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

(Noting that other answers here more than suffice!)

If working specifically with `List`s, this can be done using the `sequence` function (`Result<'c, 'd> list -> Result<'c list, 'd>`) exposed by the `Result` module of the `Fsharpx.Extras` library ([source](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Extras/blob/fdc4de3b574a1f7afed8d24af0b39e04143e0f88/src/FSharpx.Extras/ComputationExpressions/Result.fs#L80) code).

However, for more general sequences, this can be done with `Seq.sequenceResultM` function provided by the `FsToolkit.ErrorHandling` library.

Comment: Thanks, this made my day (replacing a `Seq.toList >> List.sequenceResultA` with a `Seq.sequenceResultA` when using FsToolkit.ErrorHandling

Comment: or, it would have if it existed :blush: https://github.com/demystifyfp/FsToolkit.ErrorHandling/issues/254

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution that takes a sequence (not a list) of results, so the validation is lazy.

```
let takeTo<'T> predicate (source: 'T seq) =
    seq {
        use en = source.GetEnumerator()
        let mutable isDone = false

        while isDone = false && en.MoveNext() do
            yield en.Current
            isDone <- predicate en.Current
    }

let fromResults rs = 
    rs
    |> Seq.scan (fun (vs, err) i ->
        match i with
        | Ok v -> (v::vs,err)
        | Error e -> (vs, Some e)) ([], None)
    |> Seq.takeTo (fun (vs, err) -> err.IsSome)
    |> Seq.last
    |> fun (vs, err) ->
        match err with
        | None -> vs |> List.rev |> Ok
        | Some err -> Error err
```